# Would an adjective clause be considered part of a prepositional phrase?

Tags: prepositions, clauses

For example:

I'm looking for the man who killed my father.

Is the object "the man" or is it "the man who killed my father"?

Comment: "The man who killed my father" is the noun phrase that is the object of the preposition "for".

Comment: @user178049 I assumed that, aside from nominal clauses, clauses can't be part of a prepositional phrase.

Comment: "Who killed my father" is a clause but it is embedded in a noun phrase "The man who killed my father"; in which case, the clause is not directly functioning as a complement of "for". The complement of "for" is "The man who killed my father", not "who killed my father", which is not itself a constituent.